# Missing assembly reference System.Data

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

When I compile my project (in C#) for Windows CE (using .NET Compact Framework 3.5) it fail!

```
Error: Add reference to System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
       PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

But there is!!!
Any idea what I'm missing?

Oh...the error is on the line where i try to use [Excel Data Reader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader):

```
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream)
```

Thanks in advance

P.S.: Excuse me for my english!

Comment: Thanks isim, I'm a new bie....

Comment: In Visual Studio right click on References in your project and go to .NET tab and add reference to your missing assembly System.Data

Comment: I said "But there is!"...I have the reference!!!!!!

Comment: Did you add using statement ? what is the version of added assembly ?

Comment: Yes, I use the "using" statement. The version: System.Data from Compact Framework

Comment: @HellBoy82 do u have a webconfig file? if so add the reference there also.like. `<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />`..other than that i can't find any issue if u added the references and using statement is there

Comment: It's a Windows CE project, not a ASP. Net...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the public key you're seeing.  `b77a5c561934e089` is the *desktop* public key token, which means that either directly, or more likely indirectly, you have a dependency on the desktop `System.Data` assembly.  You cannot use desktop assemblies in the Compact Framework.

The ExcelDataReader is almost certainly a desktop assembly, which in turn likely references desktop Excel automation pieces.  This simply is not going to work.  You must realize you're on a limited-resource device and fall back to using CSV files.

Comment: On the Excel Data Reader GitHub site report support for Compact Framework. Pheraps I must compile it myself??

Comment: It does appear to have some batch files that will let you build for the CF (in the 'Excel' folder).  It would be worth trying them.

Comment: I see it. I lunch the bat file, but it give me some errors (on LogExtensions.cs and StringExtensions.cs). I can use lamba expression with CF 3.5???

Comment: The original problem that you posted about is because you're referencing a desktop assembly, so that's the answer to the question.  Now why it won't build for the CF is another question, and is probably best directed at the project owner.  I know nothing about the project other than what I got from a minute browsing the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove and re-add the reference!

When adding a reference the project setting remembers the version inside the assembly. There is a setting for the references requiring a special version or not. You may also set this to not look for a special version.

[image]

If an imported assembly or class lib itself requests a specific assembly version you are lost if you can not get the source of these.

The error may alos show up if you or an imported assembly reference a full framework assembly in a compact framework project!

Comment: Did you compile ExcelDataReader for compact framework 3.5 yourself or did you just a ref to an existing library? If the second I assume the lib assembly is corrupt or not for CF 3.5.